# Can I keep my registrar dns instead of putting my hosting dns for virtual domin hosting?

Tags: domain-name-system

Currently I have a shared webhosting account with unlimited domain and a different registrar. Each time I want to add a domain, I would change my domain dns name server.

But since my registrar also offer the dns name service, could I just keep its dns name server and use A record and CName even if my server is not a dedicated server ? If yes what should I put in A and CName ?

Comment: Please explain better. What is your "domain dns name server" ? the one coming with your webhosting ?

And no, setting up a third-party A/CName alone will not be enough, the webserver must be aware of the domains it has to serve if it is shared.

Comment: The only problem you gona have is that if your company change your server ip for any reason without notifying you, your site may go down until you figure that out and update your DNS.

Answer (score 0):

So, you have hosting provided by Company A, but you register your domains with Company B?  You want to use Company B's nameservers rather than Company A's?  DNS resolves names in a hierarchial fashion. As long other nameservers can follow the logical path your records will resolve.

www.example.com has an A record pointing to your web hosting server's IP address.  As long as .com TLD has delegated authority to Company B's name servers for example.com you can hold the A record for "www" there.  Even with shared hosting, the server daemon sees the domain name in the request and will serve the correct content to the visitor's browser.